# JQuery - Removing validation for a single text box

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a set of text boxes for which validation has been done using JQuery.
We are validating any input of type "text" for using the function:

```js
eventValidation.validate = function () {
        var success = true;
        $('#modalEditBody input:text').not('.multiselect-search').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length > 1) {
                $(this).parent().find('.glyphicon-exclamation-sign').removeClass('show').addClass('hidden');
                $(this).parent().removeClass('has-error');
            } else {
                $(this).parent().find('.glyphicon-pencil').addClass('hidden');
                $(this).parent().find('.glyphicon-exclamation-sign').removeClass('hidden').addClass('show');
                $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
                success = false;
            }
        });
```

I need to remove this required field validation only for a single text control.

```html
<input id="removefield_validation" class="" type="text" value="some_value">
```

Please suggest any way to resolve and remove required field validation only for this text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the input to the `.not` selector:

```
$('#modalEditBody input:text').not('.multiselect-search, #removefield_validation')
    .each(function() {
        ...
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `#removefield_validation` to your .not selectors, as shown:

```js
eventValidation.validate = function () {
        var success = true;
        $('#modalEditBody input:text').not('.multiselect-search, #removefield_validation').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length > 1) {
                $(this).parent().find('.glyphicon-exclamation-sign').removeClass('show').addClass('hidden');
                $(this).parent().removeClass('has-error');
            } else {
                $(this).parent().find('.glyphicon-pencil').addClass('hidden');
                $(this).parent().find('.glyphicon-exclamation-sign').removeClass('hidden').addClass('show');
                $(this).parent().addClass('has-error');
                success = false;
            }
        });
```